# Is there a way to interleave two filesystems of the same structure?

Tags: centos, filesystems, backup, samba

I have a large networked file system whose backup routine sees some file systems as higher priority than others and are given more redundancy with backups. At present those file systems are visible as separate drives to users via SAMBA, but share high and low priority amongst projects. For example, a simulation input file for a project is generally both small and important to keep. The result file is very large and with compute power easily regenerated. These files would ideally be kept in separate file systems that have matching directory structures, and presented to the user through a single continuous directory structure as though there were stored in the same physical location. What would be required to do this?

Asked another way, is there a way of making the backup strategy and priority invisible to the user?

I am running a CentOS 7 based server.

Comment: There are several ways to approach this, depending on where you want to push the complexity; union mounts might be one, another could be to use rsync excludes to eliminate the generated files from backups, or to place the generated files into a scratch directory, etc. Hard to say without knowing the systems available, the specifics of the workflow, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure hiding backup strategy is a good thing. You must give people some responsibility. One way of enforcing the recognition of important files versus volatile ones is to move to a repository system like subversion or git. If it's in the repository it's backed up, else you can lose it. This also has the advantage of providing history and so on. Users who have never known a repository system are often refractory to change, but usually they only have to master 3 or 4 commands or operations. They need to be convinced.

Comment: @thrig I will look into union mounts. The high priority data exists on physically different hardware, slow, small, reliable etc. So rsync exclusion to create effectively backup 'masks' of files in one common file system won't work.

Comment: @meuh I don't necessarily disagree that hiding backup strategy is good and I haven't come up with a good answer to your point that, when you create a new file, how do you make sure it goes into the file system with the correct priority. I guess what I would like is to have effectively identical directory structures on each drive, but segregate the files appropriately. Right now the user would a) see this, which is okay, but an annoyance is b) not knowing where to look for a file and having two places to search for something if you can't remember its priority.

Comment: As well as unionfs there is also the similar overlayfs and mhddfs (a fuse-based filesystem that can merge mount points).